# How do I reference a function in the vendor folder in a component?

Tags: ember.js

I'm currently receiving an ES Lint error in the following JS file for a component:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({


  didInsertElement() {
    this.$(document).ready(function () {
      App.init();
    });

  },

  actions: {

    toggleDropdownCurrentUser() {
      this.toggleProperty('userDropDownOpen');
    },

    toggleNav() {
      this.toggleProperty('navDropDownOpen');
    }

  }

});
```

The function App is reporting as `not defined`. This function is in the vendorjs files that is compiled on build and definitely works.

I tried to import App from `../../../vendor/apps` but I can't seem to get the folder structure correct and end up with an error suggesting I can't go back to the root of the project.

Is there some methodology I am missing?

Comment: how is the app defined?

Comment: it's a global, so tell the linter to ignore it by putting `/* global App */` at the top of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume here for a second that `App` is a global. Ember's `.eslintrc.js` file uses:

```
extends: 'eslint:recommended'
```

which has the rule `no-undef` -> `disallow the use of undeclared variables unless mentioned in /*global */ comments`

So there you have it, one solution is to add `/*global App*/` to the top of every file that references `App`. If that's a lot of places, use the `.eslintrc.js` option:

```
globals: {
  App: true
}
```

to allow App to be used as a global everywhere.